# How to create android programming on layouts that have different ViewPager

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-viewpager, fragment

How do I create android programming, If I click,

tab 1 - ViewPager1 Appears Fragment1 and ViewPager2 Appears Fragment1A

and 
If I click,

tab 2 - ViewPager1 Appears Fragmen2 and ViewPager2 Appears Fragmen2A.

[image]

**PagerAdapter.java**

```
package com.papaozi.ground;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Satu tab1 = new Satu();
            return tab1;

        case 1:
            Dua tab2 = new Dua();
            return tab2;

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

**ProfilActivity.java**

```
package com.papaozi.ground;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProfilActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager simpleViewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout, tabLayout2;
private ViewPager viewPager, viewPager2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profil);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    createViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager2 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager2);
    createViewPager2(viewPager2);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout2 = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout2.setupWithViewPager(viewPager2);
    createTabIcons();
}

private void createTabIcons() {
LinearLayout tabLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
TextView tabOne = (TextView) tabLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.tabContent);
tabOne.setText("Paslon 1");
tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icontoast, 0, 0, 0);
tabLayout2.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

    LinearLayout tabLinearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) tabLinearLayout2.findViewById(R.id.tabContent);
    tabTwo.setText("Paslon 2");
    tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icontoast, 0, 0, 0);
    tabLayout2.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);
}

private void createViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFrag(new SatuA(), "Tab 1");
    adapter.addFrag(new DuaA(), "Tab 2");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();


    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);

    }
}
private void createViewPager2(ViewPager viewPager2) {
ViewPagerAdapter2 adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter2(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFrag(new Satu(), "Tab 1");
adapter.addFrag(new Dua(), "Tab 2");
viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter2 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mSilit1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mSempak1 = new ArrayList<>();


    public ViewPagerAdapter2(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mSilit1.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSilit1.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mSilit1.add(fragment);
        mSempak1.add(title);

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mSempak1.get(position);

    }
}
}
```

**fragmen1.java**

```
package com.papaozi.ground;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Satu extends Fragment {

public Satu() {
// Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dua, container, false);
}

}
```

**fragmen2.java**

```
    package com.papaozi.ground;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Dua extends Fragment {

public Dua() {
// Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dua, container, false);
}

}
```

**activity_profil.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroudscrollgrid_color"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="206dip"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/putih"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#f00"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#f00"
        app:tabTextColor="#000" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**custom_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragmen1.xml** and **fragmen2.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Satu Fragment"
    android:textColor="@color/putih"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks for helpme.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain what kind of app uses this interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple tutorial for your purpose. You can check [this link.](http://www.pineappslab.com/post/fragments-viewpager/)

But it replace fragments when normal button clicked. You can just simply move the codes into your tab's click event. Just like that : [See the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235125/how-to-get-tab-click-event-in-activity-in-tablayout-android/47548510#47548510)

> If you already added fragment1 and fragment2 into viewpager1 and fragment1A and fragment2A into viewpager2 and if you want to just simply switch the fragments programmatically when you clicked the tabs, then you can use `viewpager1.setCurrentItem(1)`
>   `viewpager1.setCurrentItem(0)` in tabs' click events.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that's not what I mean.